# How to implement Palette type for different platforms in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

So at the moment I have 3 Qml types:
**ThemeToUse.qml**

```
QtObject {
    property Palette palette: Palette {}
    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (themeContext) {
            palette = themeContext.palette
        }
    }
}
```

**Palette.qml**

```
QtObject {
    property color WindowsColor: "red"
}
```

**BaseTheme.qml**

```
QtObject {
    property Palette palette: BaseTheme.Palette {}
}
```

**BaseTheme.Palette.qml**

```
Palette {
    WindowsColor: "green" // can reimplement existing colors
    property color NewColor: "black" // and add some more colors
}
```

And I have Theme.qml for an android app:

```
BaseTheme {
    palette: BaseTheme.Palette {
        NewColor: "blue"
        readonly property color androidColor: "#010101"
    }
}
```

Also I make the ThemeToUse in the main:

```
QQmlComponent qmlComponent(&engine, "path to AndroidTheme");
auto createdComponent = qmlComponent.create(context);
context->setContextProperty("themeContext", createdComponent);
```

And somewhere I heard that this is not the best way to make a Palette which will contain only the needed colors for different platforms. 

So the question is: are there any methods to make different Palettes for different platforms, so that I can access their properties in this form: Palette.SomeColor (not the WinPalette.SomeColor and AndroidPalette.SomeColor)

Btw. I'm sorry for my english

Comment: Get a platform using [Qt.platform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#platform-prop) and so create appropriate instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a [QQmlFileSelector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlfileselector.html). It will allow you to add different versions of any qml file, based on platform or any other selector string that you choose.

Let's say I have a file called `MyTheme.qml`. And let's say, I want that file to look different if I run on Windows vs Android. My directory structure would look something like this:

```
qml/
    MyTheme.qml
    +android/
         MyTheme.qml
```

In this case, the Windows version will be the default because I'm not specifying a special path for it. But if Qt detects that I'm running on the Android platform, whenever I request a qml file, Qt will look for it first in the `+android` path.

If you are using a `QQmlApplicationEngine`, then you don't even need to make any changes in C++. The `QQmlFileSelector` is already created for you.

Comment: Well yes, but by this way I will have to implement same properties in both files + add some to android. I guess this copy-paste is not really good practice